# Weird file on my flash drive?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, event-log, fat32

I was using a FAT32 formatted flashdrive on Ubuntu earlier, and when I booted into Windows 10 (cuz yes, I have a dual-boot setup), there was an extra file on the drive. Here's what it said:

```
Filename: F:\BOOTEX.LOG


Checking file system on F:
The type of the file system is FAT32.


One of your disks needs to be checked for consistency. You
may cancel the disk check, but it is strongly recommended
that you continue.
Windows will now check the disk.                         
Volume Serial Number is 3AA2-97DD

Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.
     60098112 KB total disk space.
           96 KB in 3 folders.
         1632 KB in 18 files.
     60096352 KB are available.

        32768 bytes in each allocation unit.
      1878066 total allocation units on disk.
      1878011 allocation units available on disk.
```

I need clarification on what this is...

Comment: Windows was checking the disk for errors using `chkdsk` (and didn't find any). See [chkdsk | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk)

Comment: @DavidPostill Just to let you know, Windows 10 can't format it as FAT32, only exFAT or NTFS. I formatted the 64 gig thumb drive using GParted under Ubuntu. That makes sense. Kinda.

Answer (score 0):

Bootex is a file written by `chkdsk` when run and it is usually merged into the event viewer log, it may have been left behind if the `chkdsk` process was interrupted by a power failure or other causing the files to become corrupted. But in your case everything is fine since the checking process didn't find any errors.

Comment: So, you're saying win10 ran `fsck` on bootup?

Comment: `fsck` is a Unix command, Windows ran its own version `chkdsk`. The output above is what you have when you run it.